# JavaScript - If statement inside a loop issues

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

```
function rot13(str) { 

var yahoo = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) > 64 && str.charCodeAt[i] < 91){continue;}{
        var cnet = str.charCodeAt(i);
        yahoo.push(cnet);
    } else {
      var j = str.charCodeAt(i);
        yahoo.push(j);
    }
}

var ugh = yahoo.toString();
return ugh;
}

rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

Attempting to use an if else statement inside a for loop and having some issues with the else statement (Getting "Syntax error: unexpected token else"). Main goal right now is to try to manipulate the strings alphabet characters while passing the other characters through (ie. spaces, exclamation points etc.). Sure there is an easier way of doing that but really just wondering what is the issue with writing an if else statement inside a loop and where im going wrong. Appreciate the help

Comment: What is that continue doing there?

Comment: You are having extra block after if condition {continue;}

Comment: Code returns an empty string without a break or a continue

Comment: @Bobbygllh well the code doesn't do *anything* because it has a syntax error in it; it won't run at all.

Comment: I know, should have said “returns an empty string when I remove the else statement”

Answer (score 4):

You've got **two** code bodies after your `if`:

```
if (str.charCodeAt(i) > 64 && str.charCodeAt[i] < 91)
  {continue;}   // actual body of the if

  { // just a random block of code
    var cnet = str.charCodeAt(i);
    yahoo.push(cnet);
  }
```

The second one is not part of the `if` at all, because you only get *one* code block for the `if`. That's why `else` is "unexpected".

Comment: that makes complete sense. Reason i have the continue there was that it returned an empty string without it (after removing the else statement so it could run)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to invoke a statement after you have already completed the if statement. Your `if` results in the `continue;`and then does something else before you call the `else`. Try to refactor the `continue;`. It doesn't have anything to do with the for loop:)

Answer (score 0):

> Attempting to use an if else statement inside a for loop and having some issues with the else statement (Getting "Syntax error: unexpected token else").
>
> but really just wondering what is the issue with writing an if else statement inside a loop and where im going wrong

that you don't write an `if..else` statement, but an `if` statement and a code block where you try to add your `else` statement; and this else-statement doesn't make sense there.

your code reads like this:

```
//this is your condition
if (str.charCodeAt(i) > 64 && str.charCodeAt[i] < 91){
    continue;
}

//and this is an anonymous code block; anonymous, because you could name it
{
    var cnet = str.charCodeAt(i);
    yahoo.push(cnet);

//and such code-blocks have no `else`,
//that's why you get the error, 
//this else doesn't belong to the condition above
} else {
    var j = str.charCodeAt(i);
    yahoo.push(j);
}
```

your problem is the `{continue;}` part that changes the whole menaing of your blocks to what I've described

---

> Sure there is an easier way of doing that

yes, you could use [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), and replace the letters `a-m` with `n-z` and vice versa

```js
//a little helper
const replace = (needle, replacement) => value => String(value).replace(needle, replacement);

//the definition of `rot13` as a String replacement
const rot13 = replace(
  /[a-m]|([n-z])/gi, 
  (char,down) => String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) + (down? -13: 13))
);

let s = "SERR PBQR PNZC";
console.log("input: %s\noutput: %s", s, rot13(s));
```

explanation: `match[0]` always contains the whole matched string, here this is the `char`; and I've added a group around `[n-z]` so that `match[1]` aka. `down` is filled when the character is a n-z, but not if the character is a-m.

Therefore I know, if `down` is filled, I have to do `char.charCodeAt(0) - 13` otherwise `char.charCodeAt(0) + 13`